# PowerPivot returning all values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, powerpivot

I am trying to learn with PowerPivot and from what I saw, it would be THE tool to help me reconcile similar data in two different systems. However I cannot seem to get through the basics - I have extracts from two systems and they both share the same ID key in a format similar to below

**ID Name Other_things**

1 Eleshar ...

2 Vermillion ...

The ID is unique in each system (no duplicates) and it is exactly the same format and data type. However when in the data model I establish relationship between them and try to put together ID from table1 and e.g. name from table2, the PowerPivot will get me *all* names from the table2 for every individual ID from table1.

As thing of note: the relationship between the two tables in the data model shows as one to many and I have not figured out a way to change it to many to one. I have also tried to switch the direction of the relationship but the result is the same.

What I am trying to achieve is basically a comparison table showing ID Name_Table1 Name_Table2 (etc. for other values - I know I could try using VLOOKUP or INDEX&MATCH but I have about 100 columns to compare and PowerPivot was advertised to me like a good idea for solution of this).

Comment: Power Query (aka Data ribbon, Get & Transform data) would probably be more useful for this task.

Answer (score 2):

I have just figured it out - the solution made me facepalm.

It all sorts itself out when something is added into the Values section of the pivot table. Before, I was just adding rows first.